# Custom routes for controller with Html.ActionLink and Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a exception in de `Url.Action` function for a certain controller?

We have a controller for Html pages in a database that can be accesses with a certain ID. For example `/Page/1`.

But instead of `'/Page/1'` we want to have `'/seo-frienly-url'` without the controller name or ID.

I know it is possible to add Custom routes in MVC, but with a lot of routes it gets slow when resolving them, so i want to make an exception for a certain controller.

The routing already works because we have changed the default route to `'/{seo-page-title}'` and linked it to a *controller / action* to get the html by page title instead of ID.

Comment: You can use attribute and filter on action method

Comment: Please post your routing configuration and explain what is not working. Your last sentence seems to indicate it is working the way you expect, so what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a route name to `UrlHelper.RouteUrl`. That way you can pick which route the URL must be built from.